# Remember Me Token in Nodejs RESTFul API

Tags: node.js, rest, passport.js, remember-me

I'm developing a RestFul Apis for a mobile application (Android App). I'm using 2-Step auth using OTP and remember me token. For the remember me token I'm currently using [Remember Me](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-remember-me) (any other similar strategy npm is welcome). The npm basically sets a unique token to a cookie which the App can use to verify itself. According to documentation in the above NPM, it recommended to re-generate the tokens after every request.
However in the event when the mobile App makes multiple parallel requests, all the parallel request use the same token. This undoubted give an auth error. I guess this is common situation. I wanted to know if there is a standard way to handle this ?

Current Workflow

1. Mobile App request authentication with a given OTP
2. Upon successful verification, the App is give a token which is
   passed back in a cookie
3. For calls to protected APIs, the App calls
   the API with cookie passed back in the previous step.
4. The server resets the token in the cookie and sends back the response to the App

Issue with the workflow
The App is successfully logged-in and has a valid cookie.

1. App makes a call to a protected API /protected_api_1
2. The server has reset the token in the cookie for the above call but has not yet completed the reponse
3. App makes a second call /protected_api_2, with the old cookies as the App does not have the new cookie with it.
   Auth fails for (3)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, checking your update I think of 3 workarounds for this. Let's say we have 3 actions, (a), (b) and (c) that requires the token to consume the API.

#### Token Store

With this just I mean a class, file, cookie or object where you can save your current token, and you can update with the new token after an action is completed.

The problem with this solution is that if you make (a), (b) and (c) at the same time with the same token, the first one who finishes would update the store, and the other 2 would fail. You would have run them synchronously or concurrently.

If you want to do it this way, maybe it would be a better idea to have a:

1. **Lock**: a boolean variable that indicates that the token is being used and that the current request must wait for the token to execute and update the token.
2. **Queue**: just a linked list where you push the requests and they are consumed asynchronously when the lock isn't set. You implement a service in another thread that handles the queue, may in a similar fashion to a reactor pattern.

#### Grouping The Requests

Let's suppose that your application executes (a), (b) and (c) very often. In that case, it would be a good idea to group them in just one action and execute it on the server with just one callback. This could be complicated in your case because it would require to create new resources or think about your modeling of the problem.

#### Managing token expiration

I've seen this in some projects. You set a soft expiration for the token, let's say 15 minutes (or even less). After the time has passed, you give the client a new token, before that time you keep the same token. (a), (b) and (c) would run at the same time with the same token. Problems would happen when you run the requests near the expiration time, depending on how long it takes to complete them.

I can't give you more details about implementation because I don't know in what language or framework you are implementing the client, and I've never made an Android Application, but I think it would be a good idea to try one of this ideas or a mix of them. Best wishes.

## Original

I don't understand what do you mean by *parallel* in this context.

Try making a *Token Store resource* in your app which every parallel request consumes and updates after request is done.

If all requests are sent at the send time, maybe it would be a good idea to group them in just one operation, but that would maybe require API endpoint changes.

Comment: @s-soto By Parallel I mean multiple requests made, before the previous requests are completed. Could you please explain a little bit about the Token Store ? I'll update the question with a better explaination

Comment: I'm updating my answer. Check it out ;). Hope it helps.